# Reportlab problem in file generation

Tags: reportlab

I am writing this simple code to display a chart in pdf and other formats while collecting data to be displayed from mysql data database.
The code is running w/o errors but yet the files are not generated. Please help.

```
from rlextra.graphics.guiedit.datacharts import DataAwareDrawing, DataSource, ODBCDataSource, DataAssociation

from reportlab.graphics.shapes import _DrawingEditorMixin

from reportlab.graphics.charts.lineplots import GridLinePlot

class Ok(_DrawingEditorMixin,DataAwareDrawing):

                def __init__(self,width=800,height=800,*args,**kw):
                                DataAwareDrawing.__init__(self,width,height,*args,**kw)
                                self._add(self,GridLinePlot(),name='plot',validate=None,desc=None)
                                self.height           = 125
                                self.width            = 300
                                self.plot.height          =125
                                self.plot.width           = 300
                                self.plot.x               = 50
                                self.plot.y               = 50
                                self.dataSource       = ODBCDataSource()
                                self.dataSource.driver                   = 'mysql'
                                self.dataSource.user                     = 'root'
                                self.dataSource.password                 = 'soumya'
                                self.dataSource.name                     = 'fundrep'
                                self.dataSource.sql                      = 'SELECT fund_id, periodEnd, fundReturn,indexReturn FROM fundrep_monthlyreturnseriess ORDER BY fund_id, periodEnd'
                                self.outDir           = 'output'
                                self.fileNamePattern  = 'pleaserun'
                                self.formats          = ['pdf', 'eps', 'gif']
                                self.dataSource.associations.size       = 2
                                self.dataSource.associations.element00  = DataAssociation(column=0, target='chartId', assocType='scalar')
                                self.dataSource.associations.element01  = DataAssociation(column=[(1,2),(1,3)], target='plot.data', assocType='tmatrix')

if __name__=="__main__": #NORUNTESTS

                 Ok().go()
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is all your code, this issue appears to be that you never actually draw to a ReportLab Canvas in order for it to be written out to a file.  The general, the way ReportLab works is:

1. Create a canvas to draw the document on.
2. Draw the document (i.e. create pages, put stuff on the pages, etc.).
3. Write the document out to a file.

Since none of that happens in your code, I don't think ReportLab will put anything out.